# Android: ListView not working properly

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to change the background color in my listview whenever any item on the list is clicked.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                long arg3) {

                listView.getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundResource(R.color.GREY);
        }
    });
```

However, this piece of code is not working as expected. Its behaving erratically. Sometimes, its changing background of two items at once and if i drag my list down, an already changed color item is resetting.

Can anyone help me here?

Thx!
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

Use this in code,

put this xml file in drawable folder(you will change the colors as your wish).

**listselector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:constantSize="true">

  <item  android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">   
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>

   <item  android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/listitemfocus"/>
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/listitempress"/>
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>

</selector>
```

in your main layout use listview with `android:listSelector:`

```
 <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/parent_image_view"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/listselector"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the items of a list view(Rows) will be recycled for performance improvement...if a view is not in screen.. then instead of creating a new view for next element.. previous view is showed with new content... so you should keep track of the items for which you are changing the colour... [You can see this example... I think it helps](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-%E2%80%93-listview-%E2%80%93-5-%E2%80%93-optimized-custom-listview/)... there he is using a viewholder class.. to manage the data.. u can put a variable for colcour also.. and check the  background colour..of an item..